# Adding a reference to System.Web.Http in a Console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have written a trivial console application in which I wish to use the class HttpError which is present in the assembly `System.Web.Http`.  This assembly comes from NuGet.  Installing the assembly does not add it to the project References which I find confusing.  I then found others who indicated that the correct assembly comes with the NuGet package "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Core Libraries" so I installed that instead.  This package downloads 3 libraries and the required assembly is present but no Reference is added to the project.  I can hand edit the csproj and manually add the reference but I am thinking that doing so should not be necessary.  What am I doing wrong?

To reproduce:

1. Create a new C# Console application (latest framework is fine)
2. Add the above NuGet package

Is there a reference to System.Web.Http?  If not then this is my problem.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2013 I just executed the steps you listed and yes, it did add a reference to System.Web.Http which does indeed contain HttpError.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httperror.aspx) syas that this class is in `System.Web.Http.dll`. Looks like it's your local problem with NuGet manager

Comment: It works in .NET 4.5: \packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses in the comments which indicated that this worked.

I cannot explain it but it was not working yesterday but it is working now.  I tested it many times before posting the question.